# "Call to a member function hasProperty() on boolean" after resetting password

Tags: symfony, memcached, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 2.6.6 together with the most uptodate FOSUserBundle and the aequasi/cache-bundle (and many more bundles, find my composer.json on github (link below))

Everything works like a charm, except the password resetting form.

When requesting new password, you get an email with a token link. When then clicking that link, you get directed to the resetting form, where you can enter a new password. When then submiting this form, this happens:

I get a 500 server error, together with a 503 service unavailable:

```
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasProperty() on boolean in /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php on line 62
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web/app.php:0
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->handle() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web/app.php:33
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->invalidate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:207
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->pass() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:278
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   5. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache->forward() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:261
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   6. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->forward() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:60
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   7. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:490
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   8. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2384
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP   9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3140
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  10. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2991
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  11. call_user_func_array:{/srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3029}() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3029
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  12. Syw\Front\MainBundle\Controller\ResettingController->resetAction() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3029
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  13. Symfony\Component\Form\Form->handleRequest() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/src/Syw/Front/MainBundle/Controller/ResettingController.php:149
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  14. Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:498
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  15. Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php:116
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  16. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:665
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  17. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php:43
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  18. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2126
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  19. call_user_func:{/srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2193}() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2193
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  20. Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\EventListener\ValidationListener->validateForm() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2193
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  21. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\LegacyValidator->validate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/EventListener/ValidationListener.php:64
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  22. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator->validate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/LegacyValidator.php:52
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  23. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php:116
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  24. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:144
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  25. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateClassNode() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:354
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  26. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateInGroup() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:562
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  27. Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints\FormValidator->validate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:863
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  28. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php:54
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  29. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:144
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  30. Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateClassNode() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:354
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  31. Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\PropertyMetadata->getPropertyValue() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php:586
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  32. Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\MemberMetadata->getReflectionMember() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php:53
[01-May-2015 09:09:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP  33. Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\PropertyMetadata->newReflectionMember() /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/MemberMetadata.php:235
```

You can try this hgere: https://www.linuxcounter.net/resetting/request (You first may have to register an account)

The code of the application can be found here: https://github.com/alexloehner/linuxcounter.new

The strange thing: locally everything works, also the password resetting and also in prod mode.

Comment: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2924bat.jpg

Comment: Okay, for now I've rolled back my last changes and now everything works again... need to find out where the problem is with the reCaptcha Bundle or with the memcache bundle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oky... after removing my changes from the last two days and readding them one after another, including restarting of memcache after each change, it now works.

So I assume, I've simply forgotten to restart memcache maybe....